# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate getter method for property

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, hibernate-mapping

I converted my Idea project to **Kotlin** and bum into this error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate getter method for property [connector.model.SomeTable#tableId]
```

The `connector.model.SomeTable#tableId` comes from xml mapping. The names of both property and table are case correct.

I added the notation @JvmField that solved serialization issues, but no luck here.

Here is the class declaration:

```
class SomeTable{
    @JvmField
    var tableId: Int? = null
...
}
```

Comment: Is the `MyTable` in the error message the same as `SomeTable` in the code?

Comment: My mistake posting. It is fixed now.